# For 1/A = 1/B + 1/C, why is A <min(B, C)?

Tags: ratio

$\frac{1}{a}$  =$\frac{1}{b}$  +$\frac{1}{c}$

I read that $a$ is always < the smaller of $b$ and $c$

---

In the case of $0$ < $B$ $<1$ and $0$ < $C$ $<1$,

I can understand the rule  as:

**Firstly,**

$$\frac{1}{A}=\frac{1}{B} +\frac{1}{C}=\frac{C+B}{B*C}$$

**Now looking at 3 cases:**

Case 1

$$\frac{1}{A}=\frac{1}{0.5} +\frac{1}{0.5}=\frac{0.5+0.5}{0.5*0.5}=\frac{1}{0.25}$$

Case 2

$$\frac{1}{A}=\frac{1}{0.2} +\frac{1}{0.9}=\frac{0.2+0.8}{0.2*0.8}=\frac{1}{0.04}$$

Case 3

$$\frac{1}{A}=\frac{1}{0.001} +\frac{1}{0.999}=\frac{0.001+0.999}{0.001*0.999}=\frac{1}{0.0009}$$

So if we look at the $B*C$ term,
$$D=B*C$$

When $0$ < $B$ $<1$ and $0$ < $C$ $<1$

***The smaller value (of $B$ or $C$) brings the product $B*C$ down to its level.***

**But how does the same hold true for when $B >1$ and $C>1$**

Case 4

$$\frac{1}{A}=\frac{1}{1} +\frac{1}{1}=\frac{1+1}{1*1}=\frac{2}{1}$$
Hence $$A=1/2$$

Case 5
$$\frac{1}{A}=\frac{1}{5} +\frac{1}{5}=\frac{5+5}{5*5}=\frac{10}{25}$$
Hence $$A=25/10=2.5$$

I can see in both of these cases $A$ is still $<B$ and $A<C$. I know there is something going on here in relation to the A value and the result on the RHS of the equation but I can't quite put my finger on what causes $A$ to be less than $B$ and less than $C$ where $B$ and $C$ $>1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since everything is strictly positive, it's simply the fact that $$\frac1A=\frac1B+\frac1C>\frac1B$$ And $$\frac1A>\frac1B\implies B>A$$ Same for $C$. Since $A$ is smaller than boh, it is smaller than the minimum.

I don't really understand why in you decided to consider only three numbers.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the explanation. And FYI the 3 cases were just so I could show myself the pattern. In case 1,2,3 I just picked numbers A and B that add to 1 to make the numerator 1 so the pattern (that the smaller B or C gets, the smaller A gets) more obvious for me to see.

Comment: A neat trick and good generalization.

Comment: @blackpen what trick?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, I was trying a=(bc)/(b+c) and substituting b=kc (for a positive k) and hoping to generalize. Then I saw your answer (which is far better and simple)

Answer (score 1):

As you said, $\frac{1}{A}=\frac{C+B}{C*B}$
which means $A=\frac{B*C}{B+C}$
Now clearly $B > \frac{B*C}{B+C}$ because $\frac{B*C}{B+C} = B*\frac{C}{B+C}$ and $\frac{C}{B+C} < 1$.
Similarly, $C > \frac{B*C}{B+C}$ because $\frac{B*C}{B+C} = C*\frac{B}{B+C}$ and $\frac{B}{B+C} < 1$.
Thus $B > \frac{B*C}{B+C} = A$ and $C > \frac{B*C}{B+C} = A$